# IOException in Widgetset compilation in Scala with SBT and Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, vaadin

My widgetset compilation with vaadin-sbt-plugin (https://github.com/Gekkio/sbt-vaadin-plugin) is generating the follow exception:

```
> vaadin-compile
[info]
[info] == copy-resources ==
[info] == copy-resources ==
[info]
[info] == vaadin-compile ==
[error] Nov 29, 2011 10:09:35 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[error] Informaþ§es: Widgetsets found from classpath:
[error]         com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:E:/Projetos/smarthome/view/lib/vaadin-6.7.2.jar!/
[error]         org.vaadin.vaadinvisualizations.widgetset.VaadinvisualizationApp
licationWidgetset in jar:file:E:/Projetos/smarthome/view/lib_managed/scala_2.9.0-1/compile/visualizationsforvaadin-1.1.2.jar!/
[error]         com.invient.vaadin.charts.widgetset.InvientChartsWidgetset in jar:file:E:/Projetos/smarthome/view/lib_managed/scala_2.9.0-1/compile/invient-charts-0.8.5.jar!/
[error]
[error] Nov 29, 2011 10:09:35 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
[error] Informaþ§es: Search took 11ms
[error] Nov 29, 2011 10:09:35 PM com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler$1 run
[error] Grave: Widgetset compilation failed
[error] java.io.IOException: Could not create directory for the widgetset: file:
E:\Projetos\smarthome\view\lib\vaadin-6.7.2.jar!\com\vaadin\terminal\gwt
[error]         at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.WidgetSetBuilder.updateWidgetSet(WidgetSetBuilder.java:79)
[error]         at com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler$1.run(WidgetsetCompiler.java:76)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error]
[info] Updating GWT module description file...
[info] Widgetset compilation finished
[info] == vaadin-compile ==
[success] Successful.
[info]
[info] Total time: 1 s, completed 29/11/2011 22:09:36
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Does Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: Then there might be a fundamental problem with a path name -- I see `vaadin-6.7.2.jar!`. I don't know where that `!` came from, or whether it was supposed to be there or not, but I bet it is not supported on Windows.

Comment: Do you have write rights to the build directory? Can you create a directory manually? Just wondering if this is a permission issue. This could be related: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/7875

Comment: @miq All the rights have been granted. No, I'm not create a directory. I suppose it is trying to create a folder within a compressed file ".jar". That ! indicates that the content of a particular zip file is being changed.

Comment: @ricardogobbo Could be that, or it could be that it's just indicating the jar file which is the source for the row below (which ends WidgetsetBuilder.java:79). If you want me to take a closer look, remove all your java classes and make the project available somewhere (eg. dropbox).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I did the following to fix it:

1. Remove any widgetset description file (.gwt.xml) from your project's classpath.
2. Create a customwidgetset.gwt.xml in any package on your classpath. Make sure that this file has a unique path and not included in any jar that your maven dependencies contains (This is the cause of error in the question). For example:
   com/example/vaadinapp/widgetset/customwidgetset.gwt.xml
3. In this file, put the following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
       "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN"
       "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
   <module>
       <inherits name="org.vaadin.anaddon.AnAddonWidgetset" />
       <inherits name="org.vaadin.anotheraddon.AnotherAddonWidgetset" />
   </module>
   ```

   Here you state the widgetsets that comes from addons you are using.
4. Update web.xml file like this:

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>vaadin-frontend</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.vaadinapp.servlet.SpringApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <description>Application widgetset</description>
           <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
           <param-value>com.example.vaadinapp.widgetset.customwidgetset</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>
   ```
5. Run `mvn gwt:compile`